# How does <form> action works?

Tags: spring-mvc, forms, url-pattern

Trivial it may seeem, however I have some doubts as to how 's action work.

I have written a simple web-application, using Spring MVC.

### Controller code:

```
@Controller
public class StudentController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/student")
   public ModelAndView student() {
      return new ModelAndView("student", "command", new Student());
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("Student")Student student, 
   ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("name", student.getName());
      model.addAttribute("age", student.getAge());
      model.addAttribute("id", student.getId());

      return "result";
   }
}
```

### Here is the model class

```
package com.vipin.model;

public class Student {

   private Integer age;
   private String name;
   private Integer id;

   public void setAge(Integer age) {
      this.age = age;
   }
   public Integer getAge() {
      return age;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setId(Integer id) {
      this.id = id;
   }
   public Integer getId() {
      return id;
   }
}
```

---

Here are the XML config files:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <web-app  version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_3.0.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Form Handling</display-name>
      <servlet>
     <servlet-name>spring-form-simple-project</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet </servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-form-simple-project</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>

   </web-app>
```

spring-form-simple-project-servlet.xml

```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.vipin.controllers"/>

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

## JSP files:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Student Information</h2>
<form:form method="POST" action="/simple-form-simple-project/addStudent">
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="id">id</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

## result.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Submitted Student Information</h2>
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>${name}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>${age}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>${id}</td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</body>
</html>
```

Here are my doubts:

I have controllers methods which have annotations

@RequestMapping(value = "/student")

@RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)

The application has context path --> /spring-form-simple-project

Hence, to access I use:

```
    http://localhost:8080/spring-form-simple-project/student
```

This controller in turn returns student.jsp and when this student.jsp is submitted, it calls controller with --> @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)

In my web.xml I have mentioned the url-pattern as "/".

What if I change url-pattern to say "/test", in that case how does it work?

I tried to access like this:

```
        http://127.0.0.1:8080/spring-form-simple-project/test/student
```

It gave me error 404.

Also, when we have this controller with pattern matching --> @RequestMapping(value = "/student") is this relative to application context path? I am not able to understand this?

Any pointers as to how this works in general would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried below @ controller annotation.@RequestMapping(value = "/test")

Answer (score 1):

As per the Spring docs,      `@RequestMapping on the class level is not required. Without it, all paths are simply absolute, and not relative.`

And here you have not defined any class level request mapping,so all the mapping at method level would be absolute.Here the absolute path will start from your root context(`spring-form-simple-project`).

For More Info :- [15.3.2 Mapping requests with @RequestMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

Comment: Thanks for the info, appreciate a lot. I would have a look and understand it further. Thanks again!